# How to using Java from PHP?

Tags: java, php, php-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make PHP execute and communicate with a Java application on a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410204/make-php-execute-and-communicate-with-a-java-application-on-a-web-server)

I want to use http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ in my PHP web application. How do I do I do this since zxing is in Java?

I downloaded this: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-1.7.zip&can=2&q= and noticed there is a C++ version (I think it's a partial port). Does that help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+java+bridge

Comment: *WAAAY* too non-specific this question - what do you want to do with it? Where is your data coming from? How do you intend to pass it from PHP to Java? Do you have *any* idea where to start with this? If not, I suspect you need to do some serious private reading, or just abandon the idea completely. I also can't help thinking that whatever you are doing, if it involves reading barcodes, you would be better doing the whole thing in Java, or a C variant - certainly not PHP, which was designed primarily for WWW applications...

Comment: The question is purposely non-specific. Ultimately, I want to know how to use Java from PHP -- or how to take the C++ port and use it as an extension in PHP. It's a question that not only applies to ZXing.

Comment: You should spend some love to your question, so it's more clear what you're looking for firsthand. E.g. which Java standard are you looking for? What have you tried so far? Is it generally clear to you that PHP can not execute Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try PHP Java PECL extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.java.php) (PHP 4 only, no binaries available, source missing) which might not be helpful in any direction as you will need to research back and forth to get this to working finally (as the software is missing on quick sight).

There is a [PHP Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb) as well.

Comment: I edited your answer to make visible that the link is not useful at all.

Comment: +1 @hakres edit, but reading through the manual page comments I did find this: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Comment: @hakre thanks for edit.But its the first link i got from search from google,